# Trouble using Mix Shader node to make a texture read alpha properly?

Tags: node-editor

So I'm having trouble, I am novice when it comes to nodes, I want to have a material that already has a transparent texture also read a different set of nodes, I know how to set-up the texture nodes to make blender read the transparency/alpha, and I was also following a tutorial for "holo glitter" effects, the problem is that I dont know how to make both group of nodes match perfectly

The group of nodes I added[image]

And the group of nodes I already had for the normal textures [image]

The problem is that by setting them up that way, the original texture is no longer transparent as it should be, but the holo glitter effect from the second group of nodes is visible

example without the holo glitter node group
[image]

How it looks when I tie both group nodes onto a mix shader node
[image]

My goal is to have the holo glitter effect on top of the texture but without losing any of the transparency/with the alpha not being affected, is there a way to do that?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello :). Well, the first nodegroup is fully opaque, so when you mix it with alpha channel, the alpha transparency is affected.

Comment: I see, what should I do to make the first nodegroup not fully opaque in that case? I tried adding another mix shader node linking a transparent node + the miix shader that groups both nodegroups together but I had no luck , Im pretty novice regarding nodes so Im pretty lost, any help or guidance with this problem would so appreciated! Thank you @JachymMichal